# jw player 6 cannot find jwplayer.flash.swf using Symfony

Tags: symfony, jwplayer

I started the development of my webtv with JW Player Free 5.9.

I'm using Symfony2 as php framework that use dynamic routing and now that I had to download the 6th version of the player.

When I load the page, the player doesn't work (I changed also the way to include the player as mentioned in the Quick Start Guide) because it searches the file jwplayer.flash.swf in

```
www.mywebsite/category/product/jwplayer.flash.swf
```

and not in

```
www.mywebsite/jwplayerPro/jwplayer.flash.swf
```

I know that the problem is the routing mechanism of symfony, but what can I do to tell to the player where is located the file jwplayer.flash.swf just like in 5th version?

Comment: Is jwplayer.flash.swf in the same directory as jwplayer.js?

Comment: Did you ever manage to resolve this? I'm facing exactly the same problem at the moment. Thanks.

Comment: Same scenario did you manage to resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 2):

Use param "base" to config your swf file.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jwplayer("flash_video").setup({
      base: "<?php echo $this->config->item('base_url'); ?>jwplayer/",
      file: "<?php echo video; ?>",
      height: 234,
      width: 362,
   });
</script>
```